# Dropping Packets Intentionally

Tags: linux, networking, packet, packet-loss

I want to test robustness of my application. 
So i want a linux command that will drop few packets for some nanosecond.
I am receiving these packets from a multicast IP-Port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this and it worked
`iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.01 -j DROP`

To undo this command
`iptables -D INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.01 -j DROP`